# Infering type of function argument based on other argument with discriminated union in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union describing event type. Then I have `addEventHandler` function that takes event ID as first argument and event callback as second. Event ID field is discriminator of the union type.

```js
interface TestEventA {
  id: 'TestEventA';
  payload: null;
}

interface TestEventB {
  id: 'TestEventB';
  payload: TestEventBPayload;
}
interface TestEventBPayload {
  content: string;
}

interface TestEventC {
  id: 'TestEventC';
  payload: TestEventCPayload;
}
interface TestEventCPayload {
  value: number;
}

type TestEvent = (TestEventA | TestEventB | TestEventC);

function addEventHandler<T extends TestEvent['id']>(eventId: T, listener: (data: (TestEvent & { id: T })) => void) {
  eventEmitter.on(eventId, listener);
}


addEventHandler('TestEventC', (event) => {
  // I want event to be of type TestEventC, but instead it is of type
  // (TestEventA & { id: "TestEventC"; }) | (TestEventB & { id: "TestEventC"; }) | (TestEventC & { id: "TestEventC"; })

  // event.payload: Object is possibly 'null'
  // Property 'value' does not exist on type 'TestEventBPayload | TestEventCPayload'
  console.log(event.payload.value);

  if (event.id === 'TestEventC') { // redundant condition
    console.log(event.payload.value); // No error here
  }
});
```

How do I make `addEventHandler` callback function infer type of the event?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create an interface that maps event ids to payloads, like:

```js
interface TestEventBPayload {
  content: string;
}

interface TestEventCPayload {
  value: number;
}

interface Events {
  TestEventA: null,
  TestEventB: TestEventBPayload,
  TestEventC: TestEventCPayload
};

function addEventHandler<TId extends keyof Events>(
  eventId: TId,
  listener: (data: Events[TId] & { id: TId }) => void
): void {
  eventEmitter.on(eventId, listener);
}

addEventHandler('TestEventC', (event) => {
  console.log(event.value);

  if (event.id === 'TestEventC') {
    console.log(event.value);
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gKIDcLgBCACnAJ4A2A9nACbIDeAsAFDLIJXgFgBcyWKKADmAblYBfVq1CRYiFOix4eAYVKUa9Zm2S44FAK4R%20IQwFsARtHEspLGd3lJkK8Bkat2SnPnABBU0MKCgAaLzRMXx5Cfh83MBJyajpw3Xi-MFU4qIT1ZK1JW1YYQxAEMGAuZDpaBIAJOBBaCmgAHlQASXoIAA9IZo8AawgyKhhXTIwAPgAKCIhM7rjutPYKYCwCaH5Z2jgwOH4EjABtLtoAXWQAMkZkYFoV%20gkASmQAXmm9KkfWV-4uF%202gWmWw5mAYDkADouLNFjxVsgNlsQNBXrZ7Kxag0mi1oLMAOQZNSE0LIeGZd5fTy6TggDBUVrQ6jCSk8aH6IwQDHSXTACbs8DQx6fD4fZDE3KZVSE946djsemM5msoVgTkGYy83T2N62IA)